# Swapping records' values for a column with a UNIQUE constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

### Goal:

*Swapping* values in some table's records for a particular column that has a **`UNIQUE` constraint**.

---

### Example:

Considering the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE records (id numeric, name text);
ALTER TABLE records ADD CONSTRAINT uniq UNIQUE (id);
INSERT INTO records VALUES
  (1, 'First record'),
  (3, 'Second record'),
  (2, 'Third record'),
  (4, 'Fourth record');
```

We get, from querying for `SELECT id, name FROM records ORDER BY id;`:

```
| id |          name |
|----|---------------|
|  1 |  First record |
|  2 |  Third record |
|  3 | Second record |
|  4 | Fourth record |
```

I need the `id`s for the `Second record` and `Third record` **swapped**. That is, I want the following output:

```
| id |          name |
|----|---------------|
|  1 |  First record |
|  2 | Second record | <-- this record previously had the id 3
|  3 |  Third record | <-- this record previously had the id 2
|  4 | Fourth record |
```

---

### Obviously:

- I can't just swap the `name`s for these records, my actual database is a tad bigger than this:

  - this table has more information stored and
  - its `id` column is actually a `PRIMARY KEY` that is referenced by other tables.
- I don't wanna go through the hassle of utilizing temporary `id`s that aren't assigned to any record yet to execute this swapping.
- The *'swapping'* in question does not only involve two records, but an arbitrary long set of them.
- The records also don't technically get *'swapped'* but simply **reassigned**, with the following properties:

  - each `id` will always be unique after each *bulk reassignment* operation and
  - most of the `id`s from a previous assignment **will** overlap with those of the new assignment map.

---

### What I've tried:

I have tried swapping my data in a single query by generating a **temporary reassignment table** and using it in an `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... WHERE` query.

Here's my temporary reassignment table, which will swap the `id`s `2` and `3`:

```sql
(VALUES
  (3, 2),
  (2, 3)
) AS swap(id, new_id)
```

And here's how I use it:

```sql
UPDATE records AS record SET
  id = swap.new_id
FROM (VALUES
  (3, 2),
  (2, 3)
) AS swap(id, new_id)
WHERE record.id = swap.id;

SELECT id, name FROM records ORDER BY id;
```

As you can see in this [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46760/1/0), it works pretty well... until you add the `UNIQUE` constraint on the `id` column.

---

How could I get this working under all the conditions listed above?

Comment: Use a `DEFERRABLE` constraint

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is with the `CONSTRAINT`'s definition.

---

**PosgreSQL**'s `CONSTRAINTS` can be `DEFERRABLE`. From [their documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-set-constraints.html), we gather the following:

> IMMEDIATE constraints are checked at the end of each statement. DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction commit. Each constraint has its own IMMEDIATE or DEFERRED mode.

In the case we're facing, the `id`s will still be `UNIQUE`s **AFTER** the transaction, while indeed that `CONSTRAINT` cannot be satisfied **DURING** the reassignment of `id`s.

Simply making the relevant `CONSTRAINT` `DEFERRABLE` will solve the problem at hand.

```sql
CREATE TABLE records (id numeric, name text);
ALTER TABLE records ADD CONSTRAINT uniq UNIQUE (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
INSERT INTO records VALUES --                           ^
  (1, 'First record'),     --                          HERE
  (3, 'Second record'),
  (2, 'Third record'),
  (4, 'Fourth record');
```